# MariaDB: Complex query with join

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to get all the users that have more than one clothes but am not getting the right results

```
select us.id from users as us
                        inner join user_clothes as uc1 ON (uc1.userId = us.id)
                        inner join clothes as cl on (cl.id = uc1.clothesId)
                        inner join user_clothes as uc2 on (cl.id = uc2.clothesId)
                        HAVING COUNT(uc2.clothesId) > 0
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Start by adding `GROUP BY us.id`

Comment: Thanks, @AgRizzo. That is indeed a good start. `GROUP BY us.id` didn't work, but `GROUP BY uc2.clothesId` did work. :)

Comment: I suspect you didn't get the correct results from grouping by `clothesID` , seems strange anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you did an unnecessary join to user_clothes, and you were missing a `GROUP BY` clause , so:

```
select us.id from users as us
inner join user_clothes as uc1 ON (uc1.userId = us.id)
inner join clothes as cl on (cl.id = uc1.clothesId)
GROUP BY us.id
HAVING COUNT(distinct uc1.clothesId) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've joined the user_clothes table twice, each record in that table will be counted twice. While you could do this:

```
select us.id from users as us
    inner join user_clothes as uc1 
      ON (uc1.userId = us.id)
    inner join user_clothes as uc2 
      ON (uc2.userId = us.id
          AND uc2.clothesId<>uc1.clothesId)
```

This approach does not scale well to answering other questions (exactly 2 clothes, more than 5 clothes ....) hence...

```
  SELECT us.id
  FROM users AS us
  INNER JOIN join user_clothes as uc 
     ON (uc.userId = us.id)
  GROUP BY us.id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT uc.clothesId)>1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can vastly simplify your query.  You don't actually need any `join`s, just `group by`

```
select uc.userId
from user_clothes uc
group by uc.userId
having min(uc.clothesId) <> max(uc.clothesId);
```

All the information you need for this query is in the `user_clothes` table.

Note:  You can also use `having count(distinct uc.clothesId) > 1`.  `count(distinct)` is typically a more expensive operation.  Comparing the min and max value does the same thing.

Comment: I think it should be `uc.userID`